# msbuild.exe with tfsbuild 2010 locks unit tests "out" folder with rundll32

Tags: c#, unit-testing, msbuild, mstest, tfsbuild

I've got a problem with TFSbuild 2010 when running a build that contains unit tests. The build goes normally until the launching of unit tests with `mstest.exe`.

At this time, I've check my task manager and a process `rundll32.exe` is launching. But at the end of the build, this assembly is still running! And so when I want to generate a new build it automatically fails with the error :

```
The process cannot access to the file 'C:\Builds\2\XDProjects\CI-Base-Dev\TestResults\TFSService_TFSBUILD2012 2012-12-27 01_35_23_Any CPU_Release_Test\Out', because it is being used by another process
```

I have checked with `unlocker` on the TFSBUILD2010 computer which process is locking this out folder and `rundll32.exe` is the one. I've monitored my build and this process is launched when mstest starts running.

I don't know how to prevent `mstest.exe` from running `rundll32` or to automatically close the lock after the end of the build...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This should **not** be possible.

The TestResults subfolder,

> TFSService_TFSBUILD2012 2012-12-27 01_35_23_Any CPU_Release_Test

in your case, contains a datetime stamp that is updated with each build.

This would mean that each `Out` folder would be in a different directory solving the file access contention issue.

You could force this if you set the [results file parameter of the mstest commandline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#resultsfile).